# Keep variable values based on Date SAS

Tags: sql, sas, subset, proc

I have the following Dataset:

```
  Date      Action     
 Jan2006      A
 Jan2006      A
 Jan2006      A
 Jan2006      N
 Jan2006      N
 Feb2006      A
 Feb2006      N
 Feb2006      N
 Mar2006      A
 Mar2006      N
 Mar2006      N
 Apr2006      A
 Apr2006      N
  and so on until Dec2014.
```

What I want to do is to make a new dataset so that when it's the beginning of the year (i.e. Jan2006) then I want to keep both A and N, but only N with the remaining months of the year (Feb, March...until Dec). So the dataset above should look like the following:

```
 Date      Action     
 Jan2006      A
 Jan2006      A
 Jan2006      A
 Jan2006      N
 Jan2006      N
 Feb2006      N
 Feb2006      N
 Mar2006      N
 Mar2006      N
 Apr2006      N
 and so on until Dec2014.
```

As you can see, when it's the beginning of the month (Jan), then I am keeping both A and N, but only N with the remaining months until I get to the beginning (Jan) of next year and then the process repeates (i.e. keep A and N when Jan2007, and only N for the remaining months and so on for all the remaining years).

What is the best way to go about doing this?  I know I could probably use some sort of conditional if then statement, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like..I hope your date is in date format, otherwise substr to fetch for "Jan"

```
if month(date) ne 1 and Action= "A" then delete;
```

if not date format then

```
if substr(date,1,3) ne "Jan" and Action= "A" then delete;
```

Comment: Perfect!. Thanks very much!